# Heroku platform api - list of releases

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to receive the list of releases of my app, through the Platform api. When I call /apps/{app_id_or_name}/releases I receive only the first 200 releases, although I know I have more. If I ask for the info of a later release (i.e. /apps/{app_id_or_name}/releases/500) I do get the info.
Is there a way to get the full list of releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of values returned in a range can be controlled using a max key in the Range header. For example, to get only the first 10 values, set this header: Range: id ..; max=10;. max can also be passed when iterating over Next-Range. The default page size is 200 and maximum page size is 1000.

```
$ curl -i -n -X GET https://api.heroku.com/apps \
 -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" \
 -H "Range: name ..; order=desc,max=10;"
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#ranges